# Shopify - Webhook for getting notified on Rates API call timeout

Tags: shopify, webhooks, shopify-app

In Shopify, normally the Rates API call will succeed only if we return the rates within the 15 seconds. Else, it will display an error at the Checkout page.

I looked a glance at the webhook list in the settings page and seems like there is not such webhook for Rate API timeout error.
Is there any way to get notified of these scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

If your App is failing to return a response in 15 seconds, you can easily see that yourself by monitoring the response times of your App. Most cloud providers will log your response times for you to see. If not there are plenty of monitoring tools designed to expose your App response times in an easy way. Try that.

Comment: Also your rate service should  throw a connection closed error if you take too long to respond so you could catch that and forward that to a monitoring service

Comment: Hi @david and bknights, Thanks for your response. However, the elapsed time calculation is not effective in our system, and i resolved my scenario by listening to the req.on('close' , ...) event (please have a look at my answer posted below).    The reason for assuming the elapsed time calculation as not effective, because, on req.on('close'), i observed the elapsed time as 10 to 11 seconds only. So, now this req.on('close') resolved this, and eventhe Gateway timeout issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Got solution for this scenario as below. We can usually listen for connection close event.

```
app.post('/fetchrates', (req, res) => {
    req.on('close', () => {
        logger.debug("Shopify has aborted/closed the connection");
    });

    // <Logic for calculating the rates and returning the response>
});
```

This seems to be the best solution, since not only with the timeout, we can also get notified on gateway timeout(where the api endpoint has not been hitted into our system).